# For loop randomly takes more ticks?

Tags: c#, performance, loops, diagnostics

I was testing my code to see the performance difference between a for and a foreach loop (wanted to see how it impacted my program out of curiosity) and, while measuring the ticks, I noticed that there would be a sporadic jump in the time it took when the list was empty in a for loop.

For example, some of the output in the console window reads [...], 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 2, **26**, 3, 1, **27**, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, [...].

While I realize that these ticks for such a small time interval measurement are negligent on the final performance of my application, I'm curious as to why there's such a jump. Again, these numbers were taken while I knew the list was empty, so there was nothing to actually iterate over.

The objects in the loop are dictionaries; specifically, they have ints for keys and custom classes for their values.

Stopwatch.Frequency gives me 2533211 (I have not had to restart my system since I took the previous measurements).

Code -

```
    public void Update(int gameTime)
    {
        watch.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < _movementComponents.Count; ++i)
        {
            _positionComponents[i].Position += _movementComponents[i].Velocity * gameTime;
            _movementComponents[i].Velocity = Vector2.Zero;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Loop took " + watch.ElapsedTicks + " ticks");
    }
```

Comment: garbage collection maybe?

Comment: What are those objects you're manipulating and creating in the loop? My first guess would be the GC. Especially if you're not using value types there.

Comment: The frequency for ticks is pretty relevant. Is this nanosecond level? Microseconds? Could be cache misses, context switch, etc.

Comment: I did such an experiment with an *empty* loop. Happens there as well. Background noise from (network) interrupts for example. Or high priority threads doing tiny amounts of work.

Comment: Updated my post to include requested information; @Joey, would the objects being manipulated matter even though it wasn't iterating over them?

Comment: @usr Ah, okay! That would also make sense as to why the ticks would jump sporadically, then. Thank you!

Comment: @Sheer, the reason I was asking is that the `+=` operator implicitly creates a new object, which, unless you're using value types, will create garbage to collect. But as usr's answer shows, that's probably not the cause.

Comment: @Joey Right, but how does that create garbage when I stated that the loop is not being iterated over? As in, the code never reached the += operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did such an experiment with an empty loop. The same random delays are found there as well. Here are a few reasons for them that I can think of:

- Interrupts (network, mouse, timer ticks, IO completions caused by other processes, music player, USB device isochronous transfers, ...)
- High priority threads doing tiny amounts of work before going to sleep. I can't think of any concrete such thread but I know this is a reason. When you set your own thread and process to realtime the latency profile is significantly compressed.
- Maybe you're touching memory pages that are on the standby list. This means that a soft page fault occurs on access.
- The Garbage Collector might be triggered my something other than this loop.

Comment: You could always check if a GC was called by checking the Gen 0 GC count.